# Скачать файл с учетом авторизации C#

Tags: c#, cookie

Здравствуйте. Есть страничка, с которой необходимо скачать файл, предварительно авторизовавшись. Я делаю это так:

```
string loginURI = "http://tr.anidub.com/anime_tv/anime_ongoing/10140-tiraniya-vooruzhennyh-devushek-busou-shoujo-machiavellianism-01-iz-12.html";
            string reqString = "login_name=my_login&login_password=my_pass&login=submit";
            byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString);

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginURI);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.Method = "POST";

            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
            CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            using (Stream S = request.GetRequestStream())
                S.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                var newPageCode = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Если проверить содержимое переменной newPageCode, то там будет исходный код уже авторизованной записи, т.е. все работает. Но теперь встает другой вопрос: как скачать файл с этой страницы, сохраняя авторизацию? Я пытаюсь делать это так:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                var newPageCode = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                string tor_url = "http://tr.anidub.com/engine/download.php?id=20776";
                webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Mobile Safari/537.36");
                webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "http://tr.anidub.com/anime_tv/anime_ongoing/10140-tiraniya-vooruzhennyh-devushek-busou-shoujo-machiavellianism-01-iz-12.html");
                webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Host, "tr.anidub.com");
                foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
                {
                    webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, c.ToString());
                }
                webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(tor_url), disk.Text + "1.torrent");
                webClient.Dispose();

            }
```

Но так не работает... Что я делаю не так? Ну или может существует какой способ скачать файл, ссылка на который указана в переменной tor_url, используя HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse?

Comment: Заголовок host и так автоматически задается

Comment: @Alex78191 Убрал, но решению проблемы это все равно не поможет.

Comment: Конечно не поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-умолчанию элементы в заголовке при использовании метода `webClient.Headers.Add` разделяются запятой, но для заголовка `Cookie` элементы должны разделяться точкой с запятой.

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    var newPageCode = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    string tor_url = "http://tr.anidub.com/engine/download.php?id=20776";
    webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "http://tr.anidub.com/anime_tv/anime_ongoing/10140-tiraniya-vooruzhennyh-devushek-busou-shoujo-machiavellianism-01-iz-12.html");

    string cookieHeader = "";
    foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
    {
        cookieHeader += c + ";";
    }
    webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookieHeader);

    webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(tor_url), "1.torrent");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: @АндрейФедоров почему вы в Fiddler запросы не сравнили?

Comment: в голову совсем не пришло. А про эту особенность с запятой даже и не знал, поэтому даже как-то не подумал проверить в каком виде они передаются.

Comment: @АндрейФедоров Я тоже про эту особенность не знал, но я знаю, что если ответы разные, значит запросы разные.